# Add overlay on map using ngx-openlayers

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers

Currently, I am working on to display zoom-in and zoom-out buttons on the OpenLayers map. I have tried the overlay method but getting an error. here is my code for reference:

```js
  zoom_button = document.getElementById('zoom')
  zoom_overlay = new Overlay({
        element: this.zoom_button,
        positioning: 'bottom-left'
        });
        Map.addOverlay(zoom_overlay);
```

```html
<aol-control> 
  <aol-content>
      <div id="zoom" class="zoom">
        <button (click)="increaseZoom()">+</button><br>
         <button (click)="decreaseZoom()">-</button><br>
      </div>
   </aol-content>
 </aol-control>
```

I'm new to angular and OpenLayers, can someone tell me how can I get the map property? So that the addOverlay method can be worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the ol.css file.
If you use Angular 2 +,  add this line  `@import 'ol/ol.css';`
in styles.css file
Zoom in and zoom out are on by default.